# is csrf needed in view or having it in template is sufficient in django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-csrf

I have seen example `code` in tutorials such as the following:

```
    def login_view(request):
        c={}
        c.update(csrf(request))
        return render(request,'login.html',c)

   def login_view(request):
         return render(request,'login.html')
```

In the template file, I have `csrf_token` declared.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% if form.errors %}
  <p class="error"> sorry, not a valid username or password </p>
{% endif %}

<form action="/accounts/auth/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<label for="username"> UserName:</label>
<input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username">
<label for="password"> Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password">
<input type="submit" value="login">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

My question is whether `csrf` needs to be present on both ends (when `render` in `view` and also in `template`).
`render` without `csrf` in `view` works fine. but I want to know the best practice. I am using `Django 1.6.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be present on `template` to prevent `cross-site request forgery` but not needed in `view`.
This is just my opinion, I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove this line "c.update(csrf(request))", because you have an important security hole here, the csrf token should be send only from the html form, but if you includes the csrf in the view request the token in the html form is ignored (even if it does not exist), this is the reason that your view works with and without csrf token in your form.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything special in your view. As long as you have

> MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = ( ..., 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', ... )

in your settings.py (this is the default), your template will have access to the {% csrf_token %} tag. There's no need to manually set it in the template context, as your example view method was doing.